# Animating Toolbar along with Fragment Transactions

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have MainActivity which is implementing Navigation Drawer using the below xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id ="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity ="start"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />

   </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now i have 3 items in my listview and on clicking on any one of them my code replace Framelayout with that particular fragment like below:

```
Fragment f1 = new Fragment()

 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.hyper_out,R.anim.hyper_in,R.anim.slide_out)


ft.replace(R.id.content, f1).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The above code works fine replacing fragment with Custom animations as desired.However, my question is how to animate the toolbar along with fragment during fragment transactions.

All the fragments have their respective toolbar titles which are changed in onActivityCreated() method of each Fragment Class by following code:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Should i be applying animations to my layouts to cover up the toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question - it seems to pop up at some point in the development process of every app, and I never solve it, and revert back to some subpar solution. Now I'm back with a solution!

Answer in Kotlin, but the same principles apply in Java.

To animate the `Toolbar` alongside the `FragmentTransaction` animations, you first need a way to inform the `Activity/Fragment` holding the `Toolbar` that the animation is starting/ending. I'll call the `Activity/Fragment` holding the `Toolbar` the `ToolbarHost`

First, define an interface which the `ToolbarHost` can implement, to receive callbacks:

```
interface FragmentAnimationListener {

    fun onAnimationStart(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean)

    fun onAnimationEnd(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean)
}
```

I've also added an extension method to help the child `Fragment` find the parent `ToolbarHost` interested in receiving the callbacks:

```
fun Fragment.findParentAnimationListener(): FragmentAnimationListener? {
    return when (parentFragment) {
        is FragmentAnimationListener -> parentFragment as FragmentAnimationListener
        null -> return activity as? FragmentAnimationListener
        else -> parentFragment?.findParentAnimationListener()
    }
}
```

Now we add the following to the child `Fragment` which is about to be animated onto the screen. I suggest adding the following to a base `Fragment` class. This intercepts the animation supplied to the child `Fragment` from the `FragmentTransaction`*, adds a listener, finds `ToolbarHost`, and notifies it of our animation starting/ending.

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    var animation = super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)

    if (animation == null && nextAnim != 0) {
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity!!, nextAnim)
    }

    val parentAnimationListener = findParentAnimationListener()

    if (animation != null) {    
        animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {
                parentAnimationListener?.onAnimationStart(this@BaseFragment, animation, enter)
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
                parentAnimationListener?.onAnimationEnd(this@BaseFragment, animation, enter)
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }
        })
    }

    return animation
}
```

* This works for animations supplied via `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimation(int, int, ..)`. I haven't tested this with different types of `FragmentTransaction` animations, or no `FragmentTransaction` animation.

Now that our `ToolbarHost` knows when the child `Fragment` is performing its animations, we can think about animating the Toolbar alongside.

Assuming your `ToolbarHost` is a fragment, we first implement `FragmentAnimationListener`:

```
class ParentFragment : Fragment(), FragmentAnimationListener {

    override fun onAnimationStart(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, one issue we have right off the bat, is since we added our `AnimationListener` to a base `Fragment` class, our `onAnimationStart` and `onAnimationEnd` are going to be called from both the fragment that is exiting, and the fragment that is entering (assuming your `FragmentTransaction` is replacing one fragment with another). So before we try and do anything with the `Toolbar`, we need to filter out only the fragment we're interested in.

I'm going to use the 'entering' `Fragment` as the trigger for Toolbar animations - and when we pop the stack, I'm going to use the same `Fragment` (now 'exiting') again. So, the only `Fragment` I'm interested in is the one being transitioned *to*:

```
class ParentFragment : Fragment(), FragmentAnimationListener {

    var newFragment: Fragment? = null 

    fun replaceFragment(newFragment: Fragment) {

        // Store a reference to the fragment we're transitioning to
        this.newFragment = newFragment

        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(..)
            .replace(container, newFragment, tag)
            .commit()
    }

    override fun onAnimationStart(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean) {
        if (fragment == newFragment) {
            if (enter) {
                // Animate our Toolbar in
            } else {
                // Animate our Toolbar out
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to actually perform the Toolbar animation. You can create your own `Animation`, with your own timing, interpolator, etc - but I prefer to just use the same `Animator` that's animating the child `Fragment`. That way, if we're fading in, the `Toolbar` will fade in. If we're sliding out, the `Toolbar` will slide out. By using the same `Animation` we can be certain we have the correct duration and interpolator, so our `Animations` will run at the same time.

```
override fun onAnimationStart(fragment: Fragment, animation: Animation, enter: Boolean) {
    if (fragment == newFragment) {
        toolbar.animation = animation
    }
}
```